# Highcharts stacked columns with Y Axis grouping

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way of grouping Y Axis Categories together with a stacked column chart in Highcharts.  This is pretty trivial stuff in Excel, but pretty difficult with Highcharts it seems.

Something like the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use additional plugin

https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories